# Draw busbars in qelectrotech

Tags: bus, diagram, power-engineering

In [qelectrotech](http://qelectrotech.org/) how can I draw a [busbar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busbar)?

Comment: Your first sentence seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: In electronics the buses length is equal wires. but in power buses are a little longer than wires I think.

Comment: I am an eletronics engineer but I can't see what you are talking about. "Bus length is equal wire" equal in what ? Impedance ? Physical length ? Electrical length ?

Comment: What does electrical length mean?
Or impedance is not same in meaning as length I think;

I meant length in appearance in diagram.

You know that bus in power, is a bar for example copper bar for make connection to other lines. it is a little like a wire. without any rectangle or circle.

Anyway I think I should make it myself or import this component to qelectrotech.

Comment: @Blup1980: Thanks.
I red it again and red more about busbars.

You are right.

I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found how to draw a bus.
One way is to make a bus element and then use it.

Making an element is very easy. first select the "new element button and choose the required options.
[image: Select the new element button]

You can change the size of background from edit menu "size and hotspot"

Now should draw a rectangle and put several terminals on it. to change the orientation of the terminals just select it and from information at left change the orientation. Also add a textfild to beside your element for naming. You can put "bus_" for the default.

[image: drawing element]

After select the save button you can use the element "bus".

You can also save your element to a file from file menu.

To use your element select it from elements panel and drag it to the drawing area.

[image: usage of bus]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach a busbar element:

[image]

It's a black rectangle with a centre pin to attach wires, and two side contacts to stack them side by side.

When you compose them, you get this (all signals are connected):

[image]

The symbol is set as terminal, so that the three terminals share the same signal.

Code:

```
<definition hotspot_y="15" hotspot_x="34" orientation="dyyy" version="0.60" width="70" link_type="terminal" type="element" height="20">
    <uuid uuid="{d35ce3f4-2a25-4e52-9dcf-8d2d2adc872f}"/>
    <names>
        <name lang="it">Busbar</name>
    </names>
    <informations></informations>
    <description>
        <rect width="60" y="-13" style="line-style:normal;line-weight:normal;filling:black;color:black" antialias="false" x="-30" height="6"/>
        <rect width="0" y="-10" style="line-style:normal;line-weight:normal;filling:none;color:black" antialias="false" x="15" height="5"/>
        <input size="9" text="_" y="-25" tagg="label" rotate="true" x="10"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="-4" x2="0" end1="none" end2="none" length1="1.5" style="line-style:normal;line-weight:normal;filling:none;color:black" antialias="false" length2="1.5" y2="-8"/>
        <terminal orientation="w" y="-10" x="-30"/>
        <terminal orientation="e" y="-10" x="30"/>
        <terminal orientation="s" y="0" x="0"/>
    </description>
</definition>
```

If you paste it to a text file and save it as busbar.elmt you should get a working component.